# Creating a Map Chart in VSTO PowerPoint

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint

I'm trying to add a map chart in PowerPoint.

As of now I can't see the option to do so in XlChartType, but if I insert one manually I can then examine the inserted chart and see that its XlChartType evaluates to 140.

If I try to insert a chart with this type I get a map chart as expected. However, if I try to access its workbook it throws an exception. These two lines of code should explain what I'm doing:

```
var chart = _slide.Shapes.AddChart((XlChartType)140).Chart;
var workbook = (Workbook)chart.ChartData.Workbook;
```

I assume this is related to the fact that it's not officially supported. Is there any way to work around this problem and edit the data of the chart?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are missing call to `Activate` method.

Checkout remark from [official source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.chartdata.workbook):

> **Note** You must call the Activate method before referencing this property; otherwise, an error occurs.

Your code should be:

```
var chart = _slide.Shapes.AddChart((XlChartType)140).Chart;
chart.ChartData.Activate(); // missing piece
var workbook = (Workbook)chart.ChartData.Workbook;
```